# Select template return type from parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have something working but it seems awfully verbose.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using DataArrayShort = std::array<unsigned char,  4>;
using DataArrayLong  = std::array<unsigned char, 11>;

// Two base classes the later template stuff should choose between
class Short
{
public:
    Short(const DataArrayShort & data) { /* do some init */}
};

class Long
{
public:
    Long(const DataArrayLong & data) { /* do some init */}
};

// Concrete derived of the two bases
class S1 : public Short
{
public:
    using Short::Short;
    operator std::string() { return "S1!";}
};

class S2 : public Short
{
public:
    using Short::Short;
    operator std::string() { return "S2!";}
};

class L1 : public Long
{
public:
    using Long::Long;
    operator std::string() { return "L1!";}
};

class L2 : public Long
{
public:
    using Long::Long;
    operator std::string() { return "L2!";}
};

// Variables that will be modified by parsing other things before calling parse<>()
bool shortDataSet = false;
bool longDataSet  = false;
DataArrayShort shortData;
DataArrayLong  longData;

// Begin overly verbose template stuff
template<bool IsShort, bool IsLong>
bool getFlag();

template<>
bool getFlag<true, false>()
{
    return shortDataSet;
}

template<>
bool getFlag<false, true>()
{
    return longDataSet;
}


template<bool IsShort, bool IsLong>
struct RetType
{};

template<>
struct RetType<true, false>
{
    typedef DataArrayShort & type;
};

template<>
struct RetType<false, true>
{
    typedef DataArrayLong & type;
};

template<bool IsShort, bool IsLong>
typename RetType<IsShort, IsLong>::type getData();

template<>
DataArrayShort & getData<true, false>()
{
    return shortData;
}

template<>
DataArrayLong & getData<false, true>()
{
    return longData;
}

template<typename T>
inline std::string parse()
{
    // First test if I can create the type with initialized data
    if     (getFlag<std::is_base_of<Short, T>::value, std::is_base_of<Long, T>::value>())
    {
        // If it's initialized, Then create it with the correct array
        T t(getData<std::is_base_of<Short, T>::value, std::is_base_of<Long, T>::value>());
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return "with uninitialized data";
    }
}
// End overly verbose template stuff

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Something things that may or may not set shortDataSet and longDataSet and give shortData and longData values

    std::cout << parse<S1>() << std::endl;

    shortDataSet = true;

    std::cout << parse<S1>() << std::endl;

    std::cout << parse<L2>() << std::endl;

    longDataSet = true;

    std::cout << parse<L2>() << std::endl;
}
```

The syntax that's important to me is parse().  Within parse, I want to make sure I route to the correct flag and data to instantiate ConcreteType with.

I'm starting to think I can't use a function template to do what I want - I'm better off using a class template with static function members.

Using std::is_base_of seems clumsy - can I use built-in inheritance with overloads rather than is_base_of with overloads based on Short and Long?

RetType seems unnecessary but there seemed to be no other way to declare getData().

Part of the difficulty is that I need to determine the data to initialize t with before instantiating it.

I don't like the separate template bools for IsShort and IsLong - it won't scale.

What can I do to tighten this up?

Comment: Something like this is considerably more manageable if you centralize everything into a single class template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest to use traits technique, like other answer. But my solution is better in the way that it allows scability of this solution, I mean no more `true, false, ...` flags in your code;)

So starting from this comment:

```
// Variables that will be modified by parsing other things before calling parse<>()
```

Change your code to more scalable version.

First connect base types with data types:

```
template <typename BaseType>
class BaseDataTypeTraits;
template <> struct BaseDataTypeTraits<Short>
{
    typedef DataArrayShort DataType;
};
template <> struct BaseDataTypeTraits<Long>
{
    typedef DataArrayLong DataType;
};
```

Then define your base type traits:

```
template <typename BaseType>
struct BaseParseTypeTraits
{
    static bool dataSet;
    typedef typename BaseDataTypeTraits<BaseType>::DataType DataType;
    static DataType data;
};

template <typename BaseType>
bool BaseParseTypeTraits<BaseType>::dataSet = false;
template <typename BaseType>
typename BaseParseTypeTraits<BaseType>::DataType BaseParseTypeTraits<BaseType>::data;
```

And parse traits for each specific base type:

```
template <typename T, typename EnableIf = void>
class ParseTypeTraits;

template <typename T>
class ParseTypeTraits<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Short, T>::value>::type>
  : public BaseParseTypeTraits<Short>
{};
template <typename T>
class ParseTypeTraits<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Long, T>::value>::type>
  : public BaseParseTypeTraits<Long>
{};
```

And your parse is then almost identical to other "traits" answer:

```
template<typename T>
inline std::string parse()
{
    typedef ParseTypeTraits<T> TTraits;
    // First test if I can create the type with initialized data
    if (TTraits::dataSet)
    {
        // If it's initialized, Then create it with the correct array
        T t(TTraits::data);
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return "with uninitialized data";
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Something things that may or may not set shortDataSet and longDataSet and give shortData and longData values

    std::cout << parse<S1>() << std::endl;

    BaseParseTypeTraits<Short>::dataSet = true;

    std::cout << parse<S1>() << std::endl;

    std::cout << parse<L2>() << std::endl;

    BaseParseTypeTraits<Long>::dataSet = true;

    std::cout << parse<L2>() << std::endl;
}
```

Working example: [ideone](http://ideone.com/r4bCrl)

[UPDATE]

In this example code I also added what is required to add new base and data type.

I mean you have this:

```
using DataArrayNew  = std::array<unsigned char, 200>;
class New
{
public:
    New(const DataArrayNew & data) { /* do some init */}
};
class N1 : public New
{
public:
    using New::New;
    operator std::string() { return "N1!";}
};
```

And to make these types be supported by your parse - you need only these two specialization:

```
template <> struct BaseDataTypeTraits<New>
{
    typedef DataArrayNew DataType;
};
template <typename T>
class ParseTypeTraits<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<New, T>::value>::type>
  : public BaseParseTypeTraits<New>
{};
```

This can be enclosed in a macro:

```
#define DEFINE_PARSE_TRAITS_TYPE(BaseTypeParam, DataTypeParam) \
template <> struct BaseDataTypeTraits<BaseTypeParam>           \
{                                                              \
    typedef DataTypeParam DataType;                            \
};                                                             \
template <typename T>                                          \
class ParseTypeTraits<T,                                       \
  typename std::enable_if<                                     \
           std::is_base_of<BaseTypeParam, T>::value>::type>    \
  : public BaseParseTypeTraits<BaseTypeParam>                  \
{}
```

So support for new types is as simple as this:

```
DEFINE_PARSE_TRAITS_TYPE(New, DataArrayNew);
```

The more simplification can be achieved when we can require that base type has its datatype defined within its class definition - like here:

```
class New
{
public:
    typedef DataArrayNew DataType;
    New(const DataArrayNew & data) { /* do some init */}
};
```

Then we can have generic BaseDataTypeTraits definition:

```
template <typename BaseType>
struct BaseDataTypeTraits
{
    typedef typename BaseType::DataType DataType;
};
```

So for new type - you only require to add specialization for DataTypeTraits:

```
template <typename T>
class ParseTypeTraits<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<New, T>::value>::type>
  : public BaseParseTypeTraits<New>
{};
```

Comment: What I ended up implementing is closest to yours, but slightly different - `template <typename T>
struct BaseParseTypeTraits
{
    static bool dataSet;
    typedef T dataType;
    static T data;
};

template <typename T> bool BaseParseTypeTraits<T>::dataSet = false;
template <typename T> typename BaseParseTypeTraits<T>::dataType BaseParseTypeTraits<T>::data;`  then specializing where ParseTypeTraits derives from it on either DataArrayLong or DataArrayShort.  I tried posting an edit with those changes but it got rejected.

Comment: @bizaff I used some of your improvements to make an edit to my answer. And I also added some new ideas... HTH

Answer (score 2):

You should just forward to a dispatcher that is SFINAE-enabled. Start with an inheritance tree:

```
template <int I> struct chooser : chooser<I-1> { };
template <> struct chooser<0> { };
```

Forward to it:

```
template <typename T>
std::string parse() { return parse_impl<T>(chooser<2>{}); }
```

And write your cases:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Short, T>::value>
          >
std::string parse_impl(chooser<2> ) { // (1)
    // we're a Short!
    if (shortDataSet) {
        return T{shortData};
    }
    else {
        return "with uninitialized data";
    }
}

template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Long, T>::value>
          >
std::string parse_impl(chooser<1> ) { // (2)
    // we're a Long!
    if (longDataSet) {
        return T{longData};
    }
    else {
        return "with uninitialized data";
    }
}    

template <typename >
std::string parse_impl(chooser<0> ) { // (3)
    // base case
    return "with uninitialized data";
}
```

If `T` inherits from `Short`, `(1)` is called. Else, if it inherits from `Long`, `(2)` is called. Else, `(3)` is called. This is a handy way to do SFINAE on multiple potentially-overlapping criteria (since you can, after all, inherit from both `Short` and `Long` right?)

Comment: If it's not a Short or a Long it should fail compile.  Either Short or Long may happen with uninitialized data.

Comment: @bizaff Then you could simply delete the `(3)` overload. There'd be no fallback, and so it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of refactoring goes a long way:

```
template<class T, bool IsShort = std::is_base_of<Short, T>::value,
                  bool IsLong = std::is_base_of<Long, T>::value>
struct data_traits { };

template<class T>
struct data_traits<T, true, false> {
    static bool getFlag() { return shortDataSet; }
    static DataArrayShort & getData() { return shortData; }
};

template<class T>
struct data_traits<T, false, true> {
    static bool getFlag() { return longDataSet; }
    static DataArrayLong & getData() { return longData; }
};

template<typename T>
inline std::string parse()
{
    using traits = data_traits<T>;
    // First test if I can create the type with initialized data
    if (traits::getFlag())
    {
        // If it's initialized, Then create it with the correct array
        T t(traits::getData());
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return "with uninitialized data";
    }
}
```